# Want to scanf a 2-d array in c++ using STL

Tags: c++, stl

I want to scan a 2-d array using c++ stl. This is how I am doing please tell me what is wrong with it.

```
int test;
scanf("%d\n",&test);
VVI all_integers;
while(test--)
{
  all_integers.push_back(VI(istream_iterator<int>(cin),istream_iterator<int>()));
}
```

sample input:-

```
4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
1 2
1
```

where test is the number of lines that follow.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing `std::cin` and `scanf` input, is that intentional? What's wrong with just `std::cin >> test;` ?

Anyway, the problem with your program is that you're reading until `istream_iterator<int>()`, which is the "end of input". And you're trying to do that 4 times. Obviously, there's only one end of input. Instead, you should read to the end of a line.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int k;
  cin >> k; cout << endl << "k = " << k << endl;
  ostream_iterator<int> oi(cout, " ");
  vector<vector<int> > vpi;
  while(k--)
  {
    vpi.push_back(vector<int>(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>()));
    cin.clear();
    cout<<"k = "<< k <<endl;
    copy(vpi[vpi.size()-1].begin(), vpi[vpi.size()-1].end(), oi);
    cout<<endl;
  }
}
```

You need to use < Enter >, < Ctrl >+< D > on Linux after every vector to make it work. (< Ctrl >+< D > is eof in Linux.) To make it work with < Enter > alone, as it would be desirable, you need to use getline() to read in a string buffer and then read from the buffer.

Comment: Using new here is unnecessary, and the way you've set it up introduces a memory leak (to avoid that you'd want to store the pointers to be able to delete them later).  You're right that it returns a temporary but push_back() will copy it...just like when you do push_back(5) for example.